# Regex para obter os comentários de um CSS

Tags: php, css, regex, preg-match

Tenho este CSS:

```
:root{
    --bodyBackgroundColor: #ffffff; // pegar o comentário não importando o tamanho
    --bodyTextColor: #ffffff; // outro
    --buttonBorderFocus: #1d2124; // testando
}
```

Manipulador resposta:

```
preg_match_all('/\s*\\--([A-Za-z1-9_\-]+)(\s*:\s*(.*?);)?\s*/', $css, $resultado);
```

Resposta desejada:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => --bodyBackgroundColor: #ffffff; 

        [1] => --bodyTextColor: #212529;

        [2] => --buttonBorderFocus: #1d2124;

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => bodyBackgroundColor
        [1] => bodyTextColor
        [2] => buttonBorderFocus
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => : #ffffff;
        [1] => : #ffffff;
        [2] => : #1d2124;
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => #ffffff
        [1] => #ffffff
        [2] => #1d2124
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => pegar o comentário não importando o tamanho
        [1] => outro
        [2] => testando
    )
```

O `preg_match_all` atual só está imprimindo o array 0,1,2,3. Preciso que ele imprima o 4 também - na verdade estou utilizando somente o array 1 e 3, é porque vou utilizar o comentário como legenda.

Comment: Explique melhor seu problema e como podemos ajudar.

Comment: @SalatielQueiroz, pronto editei o post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta adicionar as duas barras, o espaço depois delas e o restante do texto na regex:

```
preg_match_all('/\s*\\--([A-Za-z1-9_\-]+)(\s*:\s*(.*?);)?\s*\/\/\s*(.*)/', $css, $resultado);
```

As barras devem ser escritas como `\/` para não serem confundidas com os delimitadores da regex (as barras no início e fim, que apenas delimitam, mas não fazem parte da regex em si).

Depois coloquei `\s*` (zero ou mais espaços) pois não sei quantos espaços pode ter depois das barras. Em seguida eu uso `(.*)` (zero ou mais ocorrências de qualquer caractere). Como por padrão o `.` [não considera quebras de linha](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.dot.php), ele pega tudo que está depois das barras até encontrar uma quebra de linha.

O resultado é (saída abaixo obtida com `var_dump($resultado)`):

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(81) "
    --bodyBackgroundColor: #ffffff; // pegar o comentário não importando o tamanho"
    [1]=>
    string(39) "
    --bodyTextColor: #ffffff; // outro"
    [2]=>
    string(46) "
    --buttonBorderFocus: #1d2124; // testando"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(19) "bodyBackgroundColor"
    [1]=>
    string(13) "bodyTextColor"
    [2]=>
    string(17) "buttonBorderFocus"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) ": #ffffff;"
    [1]=>
    string(10) ": #ffffff;"
    [2]=>
    string(10) ": #1d2124;"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(7) "#ffffff"
    [1]=>
    string(7) "#ffffff"
    [2]=>
    string(7) "#1d2124"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(45) "pegar o comentário não importando o tamanho"
    [1]=>
    string(5) "outro"
    [2]=>
    string(8) "testando"
  }
}
```

Um detalhe é que a regex acima assume que sempre haverá um comentário. Mas se este for opcional, basta colocar tudo entre parênteses e adicionar `?` na frente (pois isto torna o trecho opcional):

```
preg_match_all('/\s*\\--([A-Za-z1-9_\-]+)(\s*:\s*(.*?);)?\s*(?:\/\/\s*(.*))?/', $css, $resultado);
```

Eu também usei `(?:` para os parênteses, pois assim eles se tornam um [grupo de não-captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html#noncap) e o seu conteúdo não é retornado no array de resultados (se não tiver o `?:`, é criado mais um item no array `$resultado`, contendo as barras e o comentário).

---

Para não precisar escrever as barras como `\/\/`, é possível mudar os delimitadores para algum outro caractere. No caso, eu escolhi `{` e `}`, já que eles não ocorrem na regex. Assim, eu não preciso mais escapar as barras (posso escrevê-las sem a `\`):

```
preg_match_all('{\s*\\--([A-Za-z1-9_\-]+)(\s*:\s*(.*?);)?\s*(?://\s*(.*))?}', $css, $resultado);
```

---

**PS**: se for fazer *parsing* de um CSS completo, talvez seja melhor usar [*parsers* específicos](https://www.google.com/search?q=php%20css%20parser) para a tarefa.

Para esta string específica, cujo formato é mais simples e controlado, a regex funciona sem problemas. Mas se tiver um CSS completo, [a regex ficará bem mais complexa](https://gist.github.com/hekt/1145069), para poder lidar com todos os casos possíveis.

Comment: Bem compreensiva. +1

Comment: @hkotsubo seguinte eu editei um pouco o codigo para pegar o --bodyBackgroundColor: #ffffff; /*teste teste teste*/ pois os comentários css são /**/ '/\s*\\--([A-Za-z1-9_\-]+)\s*:\s*(.*?);?\s*\/\*(.*)\*\//' agora utilizei o (?: '/(?:\s*\\--([A-Za-z1-9_\-]+)\s*:\s*(.*?);?\s*\/\*(.*)\*\/)/' para não criar o array 0 e mesmo assim pegou

Comment: @FelipeKusk Acho que [isso](https://ideone.com/a9PnX0) resolve. Mas se os comentários se estenderem por várias linhas, aí [fica mais complicado](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13014947/regex-to-match-a-c-style-multiline-comment)